# module.exports colliding / being overwritten in node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I think I'm badly misunderstanding how to use module.exports. It seems every module is overwriting what the last one spit out.

**app.js**:

```
var express = require("express")
    , app = express()
    , routes = require('routes')
    , server = app.listen(1337, "0.0.0.0")
    , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
    , redis = require("redis")
    , client = redis.createClient();
```

`var moduleA = require("./moduleA")(io, client);` (need to pass socket.io and redis client)

`var moduleB = require("./moduleB")(io, client);` (same)

**moduleA.js**:

```
module.exports = function(io, client){ 
    this.test = 'foo';
    return this;
};
```

**moduleB.js**:

```
module.exports = function(io, client){ 
    this.test = 'bar';
    return this;
};
```

back to **app.js**:

`console.log(moduleB.test);` (**prints "bar"**)

`console.log(moduleA.test);` (***also* prints "bar"**)

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong? I can't think of any other way to do this, since the `exports` helper (?) itself doesn't seem to accept parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are exporting a constructor. You need to construct it, not call it.

Change

```
var moduleA = require("./moduleA")(io, client);
```

to

```
var moduleA = new (require("./moduleA"))(io, client);
```

or (for clarity)

```
var ModuleA = require("./moduleA");
var a = new ModuleA(io, client);
```

---

What you are seeing happen is the usual behavior when calling constructors as functions in sloppy mode: `this` references the global object. So of course modifying the global object from two locations will overwrite each other, and returning `this` will just return the global object. You can test this yourself: with your current code,

```
moduleA === moduleB === this === global
```

---

One way to prevent yourself from ever shooting yourself in the foot like this again is to use strict mode instead of sloppy mode. To do so, add the line

```
"use strict";
```

at the top of every module you write (before any other code). In strict mode, `this` for constructors called without `new` is `undefined`, so you will get an earlier and much easier-to-understand error.

Strict mode has many benefits of this sort; for an overview see [[1]](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/12/14/strict-mode-is-coming-to-town/), [[2]](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/03/13/its-time-to-start-using-javascript-strict-mode/), [[3]](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/).

---

An alternate solution is to stop using constructors altogether, but instead use factory functions. This would look like:

```
module.exports = function (io, client) {
    var result = {};
    result.test = "foo";
    return result;
};
```

You seem to be trying to do something like this anyway, since you `return this` even though doing so in a constructor is entirely unnecessary. You could just stop using `this` and use an actual object under your control, instead of one whose semantics change depending on whether your function is being called or constructed.

Comment: +1; add a `console.log(this)` before a call to `this.test =` to see how `this` is actually the global scope.

Comment: Thank you much! Avoiding the `this` snafu with your last suggestion worked perfect. I just used `var exp = {}; exp.test = 'foo'; return exp;` I'm still not sure I understand what the difference is between between `var x = require('./x')` and `var x = new require('./x')` -- it seems to have no different effect either way.

Comment: @Greg: there was a typo in my original post---I forgot the parentheses around `(require("./moduleA"))`. As for what the difference is, it's the usual difference between invoking a function with `new` (constructing it) versus invoking it without (calling it). Namely, construction creates a new empty object and passes it as `this` to the constructor, then returns you the value of `this` implicitly.

Comment: The difference is that because x is exporting a function, `var x = new require('./x')` is instantiating the function returned by require. By using `var x = require('./x')`, you're not actually creating an object, but assigning your exported function to x. You'd then need to `var derp = new x();` to instantiate the object.

Comment: It's the difference between simply calling a function and calling that function as a constructor. I suggest you read up on JavaScript constructors; something like Crockford's *JavaScript: The Good Parts* would be a good source, though not everybody is quite as down on the use of constructors as Crockford is.

Comment: I'm trying to read up on this now. I kind of intuit my way through JS most of the time, so that's really not a good habit. I think for my use case a return value may be just as good as a new object. Looking over my code, I can't think of a good reason to construct an object, since it's all just socket listeners and handling, with 'sandboxed' data shoved off to redis or the filesystem. Someone smarter could probably think of a more object oriented way of doing what I'm doing, but I'm stuck in a kind of procedural mindset.